# what is the best way to add 4 project with same dashboard and back-end in git?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, gitlab, backend

i have 4 website with different front-end and home-page. but these websites have same functionality and dashboards and same back-end.  right now, when i change something in admin panel i should manually change it in all 4 websites. i want to add it to repository in git and when i add some feature in dashboard it update all 4 website. is it possible ? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To restructure the 4 website projects so that common parts are encapsulated into a separate (5th) project, which the current 4 would utilize - if that convenience of making just one change.is what you really want - although, you will realize that you still have to repackage all 4 sites (likely adding commits to their repos) each time that 5th, base repo changes.

What you have sounds.fine, actually. Maybe solve the repetitive editing problem by using a diff tool, such as BeyondCompare.

Comment: isn't there any solution to use git to achive this? i don't like using diff tool in 4 project.